# Find $\lim_{x\rightarrow{\infty}} \frac{\int_{0}^{1} (1+(xy)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dy}{x}$, where $n\geq 2$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Find $$\lim_{x\rightarrow{\infty}} \frac{\int_{0}^{1} (1+(xy)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dy}{x}$$ where $n\geq 2$.

I introduced the $x$ in the integral and also, the limit and so I obtained it is equal to limit when $x$ tends to $\infty$ and I obtained integral from $y$ over $[0,1]$, so $\frac{1}{2}$. I am not sure it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $1/2$ is the correct answer for $n\geq 1$.  Let $t=xy$ then
$$\int_{0}^{1} (1+(xy)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dy=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x} (1+t^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dt$$
Hence the given limit is
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow{+\infty}} \frac{\int_{0}^{1} (1+(xy)^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dy}{x}
=\lim_{x\rightarrow{+\infty}} \frac{\int_{0}^{x} (1+t^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}dt}{x^2}
=\lim_{x\rightarrow{+\infty}} \frac{ (1+x^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}}{2x}
\\=\lim_{x\rightarrow{+\infty}} \frac{ (\frac{1}{x^{n}}+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
where at the second step we used L'Hopital theorem.